# dgrid editor with a dijit.form.Select

Tags: dgrid

I have a column in my dgrid that uses a digit.form.Select.

```
var gl = {};
gl.coverTypeEditorData = [{label: "C", value: "C"},
                            {label: "F", value: "F"},
                            {label: "G", value: "G"},
                            {label: "S", value: "S"},
                            {label: "P", value: "P"}];
...
             ,editor({
                  'label': 'Type',
                  'field':  'TYPE',
                  'editor': Select, 
                  'editorArgs': {
                        options: gl.coverTypeEditorData
                        }
                  }
              )
```

The select drop down displays the correct value, but when it closes the value in the cell gets changed to whatever value was last chosen.

Row 1:  Change the value to S.
Row 2:  Has value C.  I select the dd but do not change the value.  Display changes to S.  Change row event does not fire.  The cell has a S displaying but its actual value is C, which will be the selected value if I open the drop down again.

What do I need to add to get the cell to display the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple:  The two constructors are not equivalent.

```
,editor({
              'label': 'Type',
              'field':  'TYPE',
              'editorArgs': {
                    style: "width:35px;border: 1px solid green;",
                    options: gl.coverTypeEditorData
                    }
              }, Select, 'click'
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var args = targetColumn.editorArgs
targetColumn.editorArgs = function(){
   args['options'] = lang.clone(data);
   return args;
}
```

because dgrid sharing editorArgs
try lang.clone();